# Display Python output in HTML

Tags: python, html, output

What is the simplest way to display the Python ystockquote (http://goldb.org/ystockquote.html) module output in HTML? I am creating an HTML dashboard which will be run locally on my computer and want to insert the stock output results into the designated HTML placeholders. I am hoping that because it is local I can avoid many CGI and server requirements.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a templating system (see [the Python wiki article](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating)). jinja is a good choice if you don't have any particular preferences. This would allow you to write HTML augmented with expansion of variables, control flow, etc. which greatly simplifies producing HTML automatically.

You can simply write the rendered HTML to a file and open it in a browser, which should prevent you from needing a webserver (though running `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in the directory containing the HTML docs will make them available under `http://localhost:8000`)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple server built using [web.py](http://webpy.org/) (I have been playing with this for a while now, so this was a fun question to answer)

```
import web
import ystockquote

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class index:
    def POST(self):
        history = ystockquote.get_historical_prices(web.input()['stock'], web.input()['start'], web.input()['end'])
        head = history[0]
        html = '<html><head><link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"><body><table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"><thead><tr><th>{}<th>{}<th>{}<th>{}<th>{}<th>{}<th>{}<tbody>'.format(*head)
        for row in history[1:]:
            html += "<tr><td>{}<td>{}<td>{}<td>{}<td>{}<td>{}<td>{}".format(*row)
        return html

    def GET(self):
        return """<html>
                  <head><link href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
                  <body>
                  <form method='POST' action='/'><fieldset>
                    Symbol <input type='input' name='stock' value='GOOG'/><br/>
                    From <input type='input' name='start' value='20130101'/><br/>
                    To <input type='input' name='end' value='20130506'/><br/>
                    <input type='submit' class='btn'/></fieldset></form>"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Made a slight fix to pull out the header row