# Python - How is it used?

Tags: python, web-applications, python-3.x

This may seem like a stupid question, but how is Python actually used? I'm new to the language and I'm wanting to learn how to use it in building web applications, but none of the tutorials I've seen actually have a demo of the code in action. SO, once you've done all the work in your python, how would you go about using it in a website?

Majority of my experience is in Front End Development so I'm just a little confused as to how you would actually use it in a website. So I guess the main question would be. Lets say I have a simple app that just outputs "hello, world". I could easily run this in an application like NetBeans, but how would I view this in a website? Since there is no index.html that gets created with it, I'm confused as to how I would use it in an actual website.

Thanks for any info.

Comment: I recommend taking a look at one of the web packages for Python, such as [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/) or [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/) - their tutorials might prove helpful.

Comment: http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebProgramming

Comment: Generally it is used to dynamically generate an html page based on the HTTP request.

Comment: Python is not used in `Front End Development`, at least not directly. It is used to execute code on the web server, usually in the form of a framework such as Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rather elegant "Hello World" in [web.py](http://webpy.org/):

```
import web

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

class index:
    def GET(self):
        return "Hello, world!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

This script (with the web.py) is a running web server.  To run it you just call it with the python interpreter like so:

```
python hello.py
```

Then you access it from a web browser (at http://[your server]:9000)

Comment: [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)'s "Hello World" is also fairly simple.

Comment: +1, I agree, Flask is nice.  I've been on a [web.py kick lately](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16403602/16959)

Comment: @JasonSperske - Thanks for that link. That's essentially what I was trying to communicate. Good to know people are quick to downvote and close out a question that was just asked differently...